# Add LED Light to Car Interior Light

Tags: lights, led

I have a Nissan X-Trail 2015 which has two light bulbs as front interior light.
This light is very weak, so I thinking about adding my own LED panel, which contains 16 LEDs and 4x `100` resistors. This light was used to work with USB adapter, but I dissembled it so I have a spare now.
Im thinking about opening the front case and connecting cables with a cables that goes to the bulb.
Is there something I should aware when I'm connecting the LED panel? Something like Fuses or?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If your interior lights dim, that could stop working. Sometimes flickering too. I just got replacement bulbs for a few bucks and it just worked as they're made for the job (Prado though, not X-Trail)

Comment: thanks for you comment! So You say its little bit risky?

Comment: There may well be aftermarket LED replacements for your vehicle. Better than trying to fry something with a kludge.